# How many different 8-letter words can be made with three $a$s, two $b$s, two $c$s and a $d$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many words, without making any reference to their meaning can be written from the letters: $ a,a,a,b,b,c,c,d$ ?

what is the best approach to solve this kind of problem ?

Comment: Must all words be of length $8$: using all the letters?

Comment: it wasn't specified. the final solution states 1680 however.

Comment: I would look at multinomial coefficients.

Comment: Do you really have this kind of problem daily? Maybe you could find a title that has some information about what the question is about.

Comment: Your description wasn't any more precise either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need to find the number of distinct permutations of the given eight letters:

There are $8$ letters to choose from: $a \times 3, \;b\times 2,\; c\times 2,\;d\times 1$.

That gives us the number of distinct 8-character strings: $$\binom{8}{3, 2, 2, 1} = \dfrac{8!}{3!2!2!1!} =\dfrac{8!}{24}= 1680$$

Comment: why do you use that specific formula?

Comment: That gives all possible permutations of $8$ characters, not necessarily distinct (numerator), and to ensure that we don't overcount, divides by the permutation of each repeated letter. Without dividing, you'd be way overcounting!

Comment: ok..and how come you double 8! and 4! instead of summing them? I mean the denominator part of the fraction..

Comment: I'm not doubling $8!$, nor do I have $4!$. The numerator is the number of permutations of $8$ characters. We need to divide by the different ways that each repeated letters can permute without changing the appearance of the "word", e.g., since there are three $a$s, there are $3!$ ways that they can switch positions while at the same time, the appearance of the word remains the same. We count # of occurrences of each character, and divide $8!$ by #! for each distinct character  in you pool. 3 a's $\rightarrow 3!$, 2 b's $\rightarrow 2!$, etc...

Comment: @Bak1139 See Wikipedia on [multinomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient#Number_of_unique_permutations_of_words). Linked is is application to counting the number of unique permutations of letters in a word. They use MISSISSIPPI.

Comment: It's a fine start...as thorough as always mate..

Comment: @amWhy: Also needs a TU to make the green look better! :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

They want you to use multinomial coefficients.

${8 \choose 3,2,2,1 }= \dfrac{8!}{3!2!2!1!}=1680$

You put the total number of letters on the top, then put the number of each type of letter on the bottom. This gives you total number of ways to arrange the letters.